# Why does GORM use a join table for one-to-many?

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

From the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany), by default one-to-many relationships are represented using a join table.

I don't understand why this is desirable.  I had little SQL experience before starting to use Hibernate and/or Grails' GORM.  It seems like using a foreign key in the 'many'-side table pointing at a row on the 'one'-side table is the way to implement a one-to-many relationship...

Can anyone explain this sort of design decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for using an join table for a unidirectional one-to-many relationship is because the many side of the relationship may have many relationships and does not know of those relationships. Perhaps an example is best here:

```
class Book {
  String title
}

class BookStore {
  String name
  static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Library {
  String name
  static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

In the above domain, a `Book` has no need to have both the `BookStore` and `Library` IDs on it's table. A `Book` is perfectly valid without either. By using join tables this keeps from polluting the book table with foreign keys.

Keep in mind because this is modeling uni-directional and not bi-directional relationships.

Comment: Is the join-table approach not useful for bi-directional one-to-many relationships?  Or are you saying that for bi-directional the foreign-keys approach gets used on the many side?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm saying that in the case of bi-directional one-to-many relationships the many side (Book in this case) is aware of the other side of the relationship and it would make perfect sense to keep the relationship on the many side table. I seem to recall that's how Grails handles bi-directional relationships. (99% sure without checking on it).